# How to configure amazon s3 client for multi region in .net core?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-sdk

I have asp.net core application. Given S3 urls, the application needs to download file. These S3 urls may belongs to different AWS regions in the US.

```
  public class Downloader
  {
      public void DownloadFile(string s3Url, string destFolder)
      {
          //download files
      }
  }
```

The `DownloadFile()` method gets called **concurrently**. Each url pass to this method may belong to different region.

AWS documentation shows [how to Configure the AWS SDK for .NET with .NET Core](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html). In my case AWS credentials are stored in profile file on server and the same credentials can be used across all US regions. So appsettings.json looks like

```
"AWS": {    
    "Profile": "default",
    "ProfilesLocation": "C:\\aws\\awsprofile"
  },
```

**Issue**
Since URLS can belong to different region, i cannot follow documentation code. I **cannot** register `IAmazonS3` with DI framework and inject that instance into `Downloader` to download files from different regions. Because `IAmazonS3` instance tried to a particular region.

**Solution**
So i created a factory which provides instance of `IAmazonS3` given region name.

```
public interface IS3ClientFactory : IDisposable
{
    IAmazonS3 GetS3Client(RegionEndpoint region);
}

public class S3ClientFactory : IS3ClientFactory
{
    private bool _disposed = false;
    private IDictionary<string, IAmazonS3> _container = null;

    private S3ClientFactory()
    {
        _container = new Dictionary<string, IAmazonS3>();
    }
    public static IS3ClientFactory Configure(AWSOptions option, RegionEndpoint[] regions)
    {
        var factory = new S3ClientFactory();
        foreach (RegionEndpoint region in regions)
        {
            option.Region = region;
            factory._container.Add(region.SystemName, option.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonS3>());
        }
        return factory;
    }

    public IAmazonS3 GetS3Client(RegionEndpoint region)
    {            
        return _container[region.SystemName];
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_container != null && _container.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var s3Client in _container)
                    {
                        if (s3Client.Value != null)
                        {
                            s3Client.Value.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
                _disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in startup.cs register factory with DI

```
services.AddSingleton<IS3ClientFactory>(S3ClientFactory.Configure(Configuration.GetAWSOptions(),
                new RegionEndpoint[]
                {
                    RegionEndpoint.USWest1,
                    RegionEndpoint.USWest2,
                    RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
                    RegionEndpoint.USEast2
                }));
```

and `Downloader` class would look like

```
public class Downloader : IDownloader
{        
    private readonly IS3ClientFactory _factory;
    public Downloader(IS3ClientFactory factory)
    {
       _factory = factory;        
    }

    public void DownloadFile(string s3Url, string destFolder)
    {
        var s3Uri = new AmazonS3Uri(s3Url);            
        var s3Client = _factory.GetS3Client(s3Uri.Region);

        // use s3Client to download file
    }

}
```

**Questions**

1. In `S3ClientFactory`'s Configure method i am dynamically assigning `RegionEndpoint` to `AWSOptions` and then call `option.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonS3>()` is this a correct way of creating region specific instance of `IAmazonS3`? The code need to be unit testable so i could not use `new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint)`.

   ```
   foreach (RegionEndpoint region in regions)
   {
       option.Region = region;
       factory._container.Add(region.SystemName, option.CreateServiceClient<IAmazonS3>());
   }
   ```
2. Is it okay to have singleton instance of `IAmazonS3`?

Comment: A region is more than a name; behind the scenes, the SDK is communicating with entirely different servers and you can see different signing strategies even between different US regions. You should register an instance of the S3 client for each region you expect to communicate with.

Answer (score 1):

You can just inject IEnumerable of your service interface. And then find the instance that you want using LINQ.

Startup

```
foreach (string snsRegion in Configuration["SNSRegions"].Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSimpleNotificationService>(
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(snsRegion) ? null :
        new AWSOptions()
        {
            Region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(snsRegion)
        }
    );
}

services.AddSingleton<ISNSFactory, SNSFactory>();

services.Configure<SNSConfig>(Configuration);
```

SNSConfig

```
public class SNSConfig
{
    public string SNSDefaultRegion { get; set; }
    public string SNSSMSRegion { get; set; }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
  "SNSRegions": "ap-south-1,us-west-2",
  "SNSDefaultRegion": "ap-south-1",
  "SNSSMSRegion": "us-west-2",
```

SNS Factory

```
public class SNSFactory : ISNSFactory
{
    private readonly SNSConfig _snsConfig;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IAmazonSimpleNotificationService> _snsServices;

    public SNSFactory(
        IOptions<SNSConfig> snsConfig,
        IEnumerable<IAmazonSimpleNotificationService> snsServices
        )
    {
        _snsConfig = snsConfig.Value;
        _snsServices = snsServices;
    }

    public IAmazonSimpleNotificationService ForDefault()
    {
        return GetSNS(_snsConfig.SNSDefaultRegion);
    }

    public IAmazonSimpleNotificationService ForSMS()
    {
        return GetSNS(_snsConfig.SNSSMSRegion);
    }

    private IAmazonSimpleNotificationService GetSNS(string region)
    {
        return GetSNS(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(region));
    }

    private IAmazonSimpleNotificationService GetSNS(RegionEndpoint region)
    {
        IAmazonSimpleNotificationService service = _snsServices.FirstOrDefault(sns => sns.Config.RegionEndpoint == region);

        if (service == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"No SNS service registered for region: {region}");
        }

        return service;
    }
}

public interface ISNSFactory
{
    IAmazonSimpleNotificationService ForDefault();

    IAmazonSimpleNotificationService ForSMS();
}
```

Now you can get the SNS service for the region that you want in your custom service or controller

```
public class SmsSender : ISmsSender
{
    private readonly IAmazonSimpleNotificationService _sns;

    public SmsSender(ISNSFactory snsFactory)
    {
        _sns = snsFactory.ForSMS();
    }

    .......
 }

public class DeviceController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAmazonSimpleNotificationService _sns;

    public DeviceController(ISNSFactory snsFactory)
    {
        _sns = snsFactory.ForDefault();
    }

     .........
}
```